# Iterate For Loop Overtime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop

How can I iterate a for loop overtime in swift? A typical loop will execute immediately as fast as possible. However, I would like to expand the time in which the loop occurs.
Say I have the following loop:

```
for var i = 0; i < 4; i+=1{
        print(i)
}
```

And I wanted this loop to occur over a span of 1 second, each iteration taking 0.25 seconds. How could I do this? Thanks for any help

Comment: You might be looking for `sleep` or `usleep` or `dispatch_after` or `NSTimer`.

Comment: @jtbandes So if I were to use a timer would I just have a method that increases i by one every call and call the method x amount of times?

Comment: There are many ways to do it (timers themselves can repeat). You'll need to provide more information about what you really want to do.

Comment: Well essentially I have UIBezierPath and the maximum height would be 4 in this example and I want slowly increase the height so it looks more fluid and animated. I have seen other ways to animate these paths but this idea seems simpler and I was thinking that there has to be a way to iterate a for loop overtime @jtbandes

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a Timer like this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self,   selector: #selector(MyClass.tic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
time.fire() //first time
```

this timer will call the function selected with #selector when it fires, and will fire every 0.25 secondes (first parameter) until you invalidate it. So when you have ended your loops you can 
    call timer.invalidate()

tic() is a function you can define, and can have any name you want:

```
func tic() {
    numberOfTimeFired = numberOfTimeFired + 1
    print(numberOfTimeFired)
}
```

In Swift 3 the timer declaration would be:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.tic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```